# How can I know if a wifi adpater will work with Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, wireless

I've decided that I need a USB wireless adapter.  Will all USB wireless adapters work with Ubuntu 20.04?  Is there a way to know if a certain adapter will work with Ubuntu 20.04 BEFORE I buy it and attempt to use it?  Are there certain characteristics that I should look for that would indicate whether or not a certain wifi adapter would be compatible with Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Some vendors provide this information, but some don't even tell which chip is used. There is no guaranteed way. You can google about specific model.

Comment: Although ***this site is not for hardware recommendations***, you may narrow down your purchase options to 2 or 3 and ask here if these adapters work with Ubuntu and under which kernel/OS version.

Comment: Purchase from a vendor with a generous return policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used and recommend this very helpful site: https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi

Almost every site that recommends USB wireless devices is out-of-date almost immediately as the manufacturers can and often do change the chipset without notice. In contrast, Nick Morrow keeps his reference updated often and includes references to dozens, not just one or a few devices. Included are even links to purchase known working devices. Also included are driver source code and installation instructions for various devices that are not currently covered by in-kernel drivers.

I find this site invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

In best case you find the device including a info on compatibility on this page:

https://linux-hardware.org/

Or the other way round. Check for a device which is said to be working and buy exactly this device.

Comment: Another helpful site: https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi

Comment: Linux-hardware.org is a great resource to learn about.  The website did give me two recommendations for compatible USB wifi adapters.  However, one of the options was an antiquated "Wireless G" and the other had a note stating "this model is known to have problems."   I sure hope that linux-hardware.org does not have a robust database.  I'm going to keep looking.

Comment: @chili555 The morrownr github project seems to have a ton of interesting and useful information.  I love how the author paints a picture of the whole messy situation.  I am going to dive into this rabbithole and see what I can find.

Comment: @chili555    Would you please add github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi as an official answer so that I can mark it as my chosen solution?  It is up-to-date, well researched, and very informative, giving a broad overview of the situation with a detailed analysis plus a list of verified recommended models.  This is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: @hoatzin Please see my answer above.